# How to organize transactions?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, transactions

I have services been called through the 'Guardian' method, that has TransactionScope opened for each request and complete that transaction if everything is fine:

```
void ExecuteWorker(...)
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        ...CallLogicMethods...

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

One of the methods interacts with 'External' service, and in case if that interaction fails all my transaction fails also. As a result, I don't save required data (been calculated before request to external service.

```
void DoLogic1(...)
{
    CalculateSomeData(...);
    SaveCalculatedData(...);

    DoRequestToExternalService(...);
}
```

What is the best way to resolve that issue?

Application is written using C#, .NET 4.0, MS SQL 2008.

Myself I see two solutions

1. Using try/catch:

   void DoLogic11(...)
   {
       CalculateSomeData(...);
       SaveCalculatedData(...);

   ```
   try
   {
       DoRequestToExternalService(...);
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
       LogError(...);
   }
   ```

   }

The lack of this approach is that I'm hiding exception from the caller. But I would like to pass error outside as an exception (to be logged, etc).

1. Using 'Nested transcation', but I not sure how that works.

Here is my vision it should be:

```
void DoLogic12(...)
{
    using (TransactionScope scopeNested = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
        CalculateSomeData(...);
        SaveCalculatedData(...);
        scopeNested.Complete()
    }

    DoRequestToExternalService(...);        
}
```

I've implemented that, tried to use, but it seems that nested transcation is committed only in case when external is committed also.

Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure to have correctly understand your problem... Consider anyway that you can also create a transaction with the RequiresNew flag. In this case transaction are immediately committed without wait the external transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to change my 'ExecuteWorker' method to create transaction conditionally. Therefore I'm able to create transaction in the 'DoLogicX' method itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood it correctly. Can you put all your logic methods in one try-catch? Each call is a separate transaction using **TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew**

```
void DoLogic1(...)
{
    try
    {
        CalculateSomeData(...);
        SaveCalculatedData(...);
        DoRequestToExternalService(...);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(...)
        throw;
    }
}
```

> But I would like to pass error outside
>   as an exception (to be logged, etc).

Can you use **throw**?

Comment: If I do 'throw' then my external transaction will fail. see method 'ExecuteWorker' - if any exception inside is occurred transaction won't be committed... it seems like my idea with external transaction scope doesn't work... I don't need to create it ALWAYS...